# Database Inconsistencies

Tags: mysql, database, computer-science

I have a Users table with a State column in it. The state column has both codes and full names of US states (MN and Minnesota). I would like for them to be all full names. I need a MYSQL query to fix that throughout the table. Thank you.

Comment: That's not enough. You need to show us how exactly the data being stored in the table. Is it really `MN and Minnesota`? Or `MN - Minnesota`? Or `Minnesota(MN)`? What if the data stored is inconsistent? Sometimes its `MN - Minnesota`, sometimes its `Minnesota(MN)`? [Please update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65316881/edit) with your sample data table in textual form (5 - 10 rows maybe) and don't forget to include extra information like data inconsistencies etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
update Users set State=
    case State
        when 'MN' then 'Minnesota'
        when 'AL' then 'Alabama'
        ...
        else State
    end;
```

Comment: For the sake of my sanity, I'd probably list the states alphabetically

Answer (score -1):

Here's the code if each row is formatted like this 'Code and Fullname'...

```
UPDATE `Users` SET `columnName` = SUBSTRING(`columnName`, POSITION("and " IN `columnName`) + 4);
```